# How to Clone a whole grid of Controls?

Tags: wpf, grid, clone

I have the following code and basically what i am not able to figure out is how to clone the whole grid and make a blank copy of them side by side.... for a clear understanding this is something to do with hospital application and the grid is related to a pregnancy so when said 'ADD CHILD' button a whole new grid should be created during run time, thanks for the help below is a link that might help people cause i tried it but not sure how to display it

[How can you clone a WPF object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541/how-can-you-clone-a-wpf-object)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the frameworks I have come across so far (both web and desktop) provide this option. I feel it would be very useful if implemented.

Comment: Most answers provided here won't be of any use if the control to be cloned are being initialized by some third-party code.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the object you are want to "clone" in a `DataTemplate` and reference this template from an `ItemsControl`, then when you need another grid add another item to the items control (or even better to the list the control is bound to) and the `ItemsControl` will create a new grid and bind it the new object.

For an example take a look at [this post](http://www.nbdtech.com/blog/archive/2007/08/23/WPF-Image-Viewer-Part-4-Data-Templates-and-Resources.aspx) on my blog.

Here is an example for this application (I left only the relevant parts and I didn't test it, so there are probably some typos there):

```
<Window ... >
   <Window.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate">
         <Grid>
            ...
            <TextBlock Text="Delivery Date:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DeliveryDate}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Delivery Time:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DeliveryTime}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
            ...
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </Window.Resources>
   ...
      <Button Content="AddChild" Click="AddChildClick"/>
   ...
      <ScrollViewer>
          <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllChildren}" ItemsTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}">
              <ItemsControl.PanelTemplate>
                  <ItemsPanelTemplate><StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/></ItemPanelTemplate>
              <ItemsControl.PanelTemplate>
      </ScrollViewer>
    ...
</Window>
```

And in cs:

1. Set an object with all the form data as the Window's `DataContext`. I'll call this class `PostDelveryData`.
2. Create another class with the repeating data. I'll call it `ChildDeliveryData`.
3. Add a property of type `ObservableCollection<ChildDeliveryData>` called `AllChildren` to `PostDeliveryData`; it's important it'll be `ObservableCollection` and not any other type of collection.
4. Now, for the magic:

   ```
   private void AddChildClick(object sender, RoutedEvetnArgs e)
   {
      ((PostDeliveryData)DataContext).AllChildren.Add(new ChildDeliveryData());
   }
   ```

And when you add the new item to the list another copy of the entire data template will be added.

Comment: so using child grid control i will be able to make a whole new grid copy of the existing one?...http://www.flickr.com/photos/14529949@N07/3262167943/ so as from the diagram you can understand that i need to add this whole lot of controls if you like to see full project please let me know thankyou

Comment: its really a bit confusing any sample application before i blow my brains thinking and trying to figure out

Comment: hey NIR i tried what u said man but i find it a bit difficult using it not really getting the idea...gues i am a noob after all...please help got till firday to hand in...
I have uploaded the file at the following link 
http://tinyurl.com/ajyvnw
my fren suggested using control library please assist.

Comment: Oh i forgot to say thanks before hand and also i know u r worried about the tinyurl could be virus u might be thinking please don't suspect me i did it as i am being counted of the characters thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you're using the correct approach here. I would approach the problem by creating a "ChildGridControl" with a Child property, and let the Child property handle the databinding. Adding a new child to the GUI would involve creating a new instance of the ChildGridControl.

Comment: so using child grid control i will be able to make a whole new grid copy of the existing one?...http://www.flickr.com/photos/14529949@N07/3262167943/    so as from the diagram you can understand that i need to add this whole lot of controls if you like to see full project please let me know thankyou

Comment: Well, the point I was making was that you don't need to "copy" that child grid. If you encapsulate the child grid into a user control, you can add as many instances of the user control as you'd like. Another option is to only have one grid on the page, but populate it with a different Child.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you should create a UserControl, which wraps your Grid and subsequent controls inside. And use this User control anywhere you wanted to replicate that UI.

Comment: so using child grid control i will be able to make a whole new grid copy of the existing one?...http://www.flickr.com/photos/14529949@N07/3262167943/ so as from the diagram you can understand that i need to add this whole lot of controls if you like to see full project please let me know thankyou

Comment: That is my answer , You have to create a UserControl with those items inside.