# Binding does not have a Clone method, whats an effective way to copy it

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, clone

I wish to copy a binding, this is so i can set a different source property on it without affecting the original binding. Is this just a case of setting all of the properties on the new binding to be the same as the old?

Comment: I have now found that I don't need to copy a binding, in code I can use a binding more than once on different elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can't find a method to do this already create an exetension for Binding.

```
    public static class BindingExtensions
{
    public static Binding Clone(this Binding binding)
    {
        var cloned = new Binding();
        //copy properties here
        return cloned;
    }
}

public void doWork()
{
    Binding b= new Binding();
    Binding nb = b.Clone(); 
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is my solution to the problem:

```
public static BindingBase CloneBinding(BindingBase bindingBase, object source)
{
    var binding = bindingBase as Binding;
    if (binding != null)
    {
        var result = new Binding
                         {
                             Source = source,
                             AsyncState = binding.AsyncState,
                             BindingGroupName = binding.BindingGroupName,
                             BindsDirectlyToSource = binding.BindsDirectlyToSource,
                             Converter = binding.Converter,
                             ConverterCulture = binding.ConverterCulture,
                             ConverterParameter = binding.ConverterParameter,
                             //ElementName = binding.ElementName,
                             FallbackValue = binding.FallbackValue,
                             IsAsync = binding.IsAsync,
                             Mode = binding.Mode,
                             NotifyOnSourceUpdated = binding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated,
                             NotifyOnTargetUpdated = binding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated,
                             NotifyOnValidationError = binding.NotifyOnValidationError,
                             Path = binding.Path,
                             //RelativeSource = binding.RelativeSource,
                             StringFormat = binding.StringFormat,
                             TargetNullValue = binding.TargetNullValue,
                             UpdateSourceExceptionFilter = binding.UpdateSourceExceptionFilter,
                             UpdateSourceTrigger = binding.UpdateSourceTrigger,
                             ValidatesOnDataErrors = binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors,
                             ValidatesOnExceptions = binding.ValidatesOnExceptions,
                             XPath = binding.XPath,
                         };

        foreach (var validationRule in binding.ValidationRules)
        {
            result.ValidationRules.Add(validationRule);
        }

        return result;
    }

    var multiBinding = bindingBase as MultiBinding;
    if (multiBinding != null)
    {
        var result = new MultiBinding
                         {
                             BindingGroupName = multiBinding.BindingGroupName,
                             Converter = multiBinding.Converter,
                             ConverterCulture = multiBinding.ConverterCulture,
                             ConverterParameter = multiBinding.ConverterParameter,
                             FallbackValue = multiBinding.FallbackValue,
                             Mode = multiBinding.Mode,
                             NotifyOnSourceUpdated = multiBinding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated,
                             NotifyOnTargetUpdated = multiBinding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated,
                             NotifyOnValidationError = multiBinding.NotifyOnValidationError,
                             StringFormat = multiBinding.StringFormat,
                             TargetNullValue = multiBinding.TargetNullValue,
                             UpdateSourceExceptionFilter = multiBinding.UpdateSourceExceptionFilter,
                             UpdateSourceTrigger = multiBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger,
                             ValidatesOnDataErrors = multiBinding.ValidatesOnDataErrors,
                             ValidatesOnExceptions = multiBinding.ValidatesOnDataErrors,
                         };

        foreach (var validationRule in multiBinding.ValidationRules)
        {
            result.ValidationRules.Add(validationRule);
        }

        foreach (var childBinding in multiBinding.Bindings)
        {
            result.Bindings.Add(CloneBinding(childBinding, source));
        }

        return result;
    }

    var priorityBinding = bindingBase as PriorityBinding;
    if (priorityBinding != null)
    {
        var result = new PriorityBinding
                         {
                             BindingGroupName = priorityBinding.BindingGroupName,
                             FallbackValue = priorityBinding.FallbackValue,
                             StringFormat = priorityBinding.StringFormat,
                             TargetNullValue = priorityBinding.TargetNullValue,
                         };

        foreach (var childBinding in priorityBinding.Bindings)
        {
            result.Bindings.Add(CloneBinding(childBinding, source));
        }

        return result;
    }

    throw new NotSupportedException("Failed to clone binding");
}
```

Comment: Why are ElementName and RelativeSource commented out?  I'm guessing you encountered an issue when trying to clone those properties?

Comment: Binding only allows you to set one of ElementName, RelativeSource or Source. If you try to set more than one, it throws an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: I was having trouble using the above, except I was copying the source from the old binding to the new. In my case the binding inherits the DataContext as its source. When I copy source, it explicitly sets null as the source which apparently causes the DataContext not to be used. To overcome this, use: 'Source = binding.Source ?? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

Comment: Thanks, you saved me an hour!

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed in BindingBase decompiled code that it has an internal `Clone()` method, so another (unsafe, don't try at home, use at your own risk, etc.) solution would be to use reflection to bypass the compiler's access limitations:

```
public static BindingBase CloneBinding(BindingBase bindingBase, BindingMode mode = BindingMode.Default)
{
    var cloneMethodInfo = typeof(BindingBase).GetMethod("Clone", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    return (BindingBase) cloneMethodInfo.Invoke(bindingBase, new object[] { mode });
}
```

Didn't try it, though, so it might not work.

Comment: Worked for me!! With the caveat that the binding is cloned *including* the private _isSealed field. I needed to set NotifyOnTargetUpdated to true (on an existing binding), which is not possible after the binding has been used somewhere. Instead, I cloned it, reset the _isSealed field, set NotifyOnTargetUpdated and then set this binding back to the original DependencyObject (replacing the original).

Answer (score 0):

I just started using this. It's not the most efficient but is fast enough for me so far. It's simple and in theory shouldn't miss any properties.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Xml;

static Binding CloneBinding(Binding binding)
{
    var xaml = XamlWriter.Save(binding);
    var stringReader = new StringReader(xaml);
    var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    return (Binding)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
}
```

Inspired by another question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33036/316760).