# How can I copy a WPF Databinding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Binding does not have a Clone method, whats an effective way to copy it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911532/binding-does-not-have-a-clone-method-whats-an-effective-way-to-copy-it)

I have a data binding which was setup in XAML and I want to change it in code behind.  I would like to change the binding mode from TwoWay to OneTime, but this is not allowed since the binding has already been used by the time my code is run.  Is there an easy way to copy a binding so I can change the mode?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911532/binding-does-not-have-a-clone-method-whats-an-effective-way-to-copy-it