# How to set and get updatesourcetrigger of a textbox in codebehind?

Tags: wpf, textbox, updatesourcetrigger

Just a short question :
In wpf, how do I set and get updatesourcetrigger of a textbox in codebehind ?
Thanks

***Update :***
I follow AngleWPF's code :

```
        var bndExp = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, TextBox.TextProperty);

        var myBinding
          = bndExp.ParentBinding;

        var updateSourceTrigger = myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger;
```

But I got the exception :

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll Additional information: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What do you mean by `UpdateSourceTrigger` of `TextBox`? You mean to say `UpdateSourceTrigger` of `TextBox.TextProperty`'s `Binding`?

E.g. if you have a `TextBox` named `myTextBox` having its `Text` property bound to some source then you can easily **get** it's `UpdateSourceTrigger` and `Binding` object via `GetBindingExpression()` call.

```
   var bndExp
     = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(myTextBox, TextBox.Textproperty);

   var myBinding
     = bndExp.ParentBinding; 

   var updateSourceTrigger
     = myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger;
```

But it is tricky to **set**  `UpdateSourceTrigger` for an already used binding. E.g. in the above case you wont be able to set the `myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger` to something else. This is not allowed when a binding object is already in use.

You may have to **deep clone** the binding object and set new `UpdateSourceTrigger` to it and assign it back to the `TextBox`. Cloning does not exist for `Binding` class. You may have to write your own cloning code for the same.

```
  var newBinding = Clone(myBinding); //// <--- You may have to code this function.
  newBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit;
  myTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, newBinding);
```

Alternately ou can also try to **detatch** the existing Binding and update it and assign it back...

```
  myTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, null);
  myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit;
  myTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Let me know if any of these tips helps.

Comment: Hi AngelWPF, I follow your code but got the exception. In fact, I want to set all of my textbox.TextProperty's Binding UpdateSourceTrigger into PropertyChanged so I though I could do it in my textbox baseclass (all of my textboxs are inherited from one baseclass)

Comment: AngleWPF, Exception:Thrown: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." (System.NullReferenceException)
A System.NullReferenceException was thrown: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Did u put a debug pointer in the code and see which variable is coming as null? `bndExp` will come null if there is no existing binding done on `TextProperty` of the `TextBox`. Also I hope `this` is a `TextBox` object. In which function inside your custom text box are you checking this code?

Comment: I tried putting try catch around the code and realize that the exception doesn't come from there.

Comment: I know this answer is 7-years old, but, in case it helps anyone, the cloning option worked for me, and, with the help of [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541/how-can-you-clone-a-wpf-object#33036), it was possible to clone the binding in 3 lines. Since there is not much room in these comments, this is the "ugly" one-liner method to do the cloning: `public static Binding Clone(Binding binding) => (Binding)XamlReader.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(XamlWriter.Save(binding))));`. This 1 line requires using `System.Xml`, `System.Windows.Markup`, & `System.IO`

Comment: As a P.S. to the previous comment, I must say that, after cloning, I lost the functionality of a trigger in the textbox's XAML that would switch the property that was bound to the textbox's `Text` depending on the textbox's focus state. Therefore, I was forced to simulate the switch in code by re-cloning the `Binding` in the textbox's `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events, modifying the bound property in the clone.

Answer (score 2):

A another way to implement it is setting binding in TextBox loaded eventhandler.
Below is the xaml of TextBox:

```
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" 
             x:Name="txtName"
             Text="{Binding Name}"
             Loaded="TxtName_OnLoaded" />
```

Now in code behind for TxtName_OnLoaded eventhandler will will create new Binding object and will initialize it as per our needs. Also we will add ValidationRule into it.

```
    private void TxtName_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      ApplicationViewModel appVm = this.DataContext as ApplicationViewModel;
      TextBox TxtName = sender as TextBox;

      if (TxtName == null)
        return;

      Binding newBinding = new Binding("Name");
      newBinding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
      newBinding.ValidatesOnExceptions = true;
      newBinding.NotifyOnValidationError = true;
      newBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
      validator.ErrorMessage = "Labware name should be unique.";
      validator.ApplicationViewModel = appVm;
      if (!newBinding.ValidationRules.Contains(validator))
        newBinding.ValidationRules.Add(validator);
      TxtName.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, newBinding);
    }
```

As you can see in above implementation we have created an object of Binding with new binding path. Also assigned UpdateSourceTrigger to newly created Binding object.

A binding can have multiple validation rules. We will add a validation rule into it. Now we can set the binding to the TextProperty of textbox.

**Benefits:** You can bind multiple dependency objects to the properties of Validation Rule object from code behind which is not possible with xaml. For example:

I used it to validate inputs on TextChanged event, where I compare input with the list of Items stored as public ObservableCollection property, bound with Grid, in ApplicationViewModel. Code of ValidationRule is as follows:

```
    public class UniqueValueValidator : ValidationRule
  {
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public ApplicationViewModel ApplicationViewModel { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
      if (value == null)
        return null;

      var lws = ApplicationViewModel.Inputs.Where(s => s.Name.Equals(value.ToString())).FirstOrDefault();
      if (lws != null)
        return new ValidationResult(false, ErrorMessage);


      return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
  }
```

Above code takes input and checks availability in the "Inputs" observable collection. Rule give false ValidationResult if value exists. Through this implementation I check uniqueness of inputs on run-time.

Hope you guys have enjoyed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this the right way to do this:

```
 Binding binding = new Binding();

 binding.Source = new CustomerViewModel();;
 binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Customer.Name");
 binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
 binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
 txtCustName.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```