# How to Serialize an Image Control whose source is set at runtime?

Tags: wpf, serialization, wpf-controls

I have a Grid containing several controls, the most important being three image controls.
I need to make a duplicate of this Grid. Serializing by saving the XAML in a MemoryStream doesnt seem to help because, obviously, when I set the source of the Image Control in the code behind at runtime, this change is not reflected in the XAML designer code.  [Technically it is, but as

```
<Image.Source> System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap</Image.Source>
```

and I get some wierd exception]
So, how can I serialize my Image control?
More generally, how can I Clone my Grid control to reflect any changes to the UI that happened after the window loaded?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, I think you just need to create a clone of your grid at runtime. If so take a look at these threads
[How can you clone a WPF object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541/how-can-you-clone-a-wpf-object)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-HK/wpf/thread/e1a63ed2-a432-4c46-8f3b-4f172702cd7c

**Use this function to clone an Object**

```
public static T DeepClone<T>(T from)
    {
        using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
            f.Serialize(s, from);
            s.Position = 0;
            object clone = f.Deserialize(s);

            return (T)clone;
        }
    }
```

above function was by [Arcturus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/900/arcturus)

Comment: This raises a `SerializationException`. `Grid` is not marked as serializable.