# Copy control button in run time

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi all. I create an application with some (WPF) forms. I have a button on one form. I want to, at run time, copy this button onto a second form without having to create it again.

For example: I have 'X' button on form 1. At run time, I create a copy of this button on form 2 with all of the same property values as the original button on form 1.

The button:

```
<Button Content="Open Window" Click="ButtonClicked" Height="25"
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="379,264,0,0" Name="button1" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
```

Any chance I can avoid having to reproduce this code?

Comment: So first tell us what you are really using, wpf or winforms

Comment: I use WPF in my application

Comment: I removed Winforms, since that isn't used then.

Comment: Sorry for this error thanks

Comment: why  you  should  copy this button  could you  give us  the reason

Comment: i want to use this button more once to do some operation from it's properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own style for button in `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfButton.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="myBtnStyle" TargetType="Button" >
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Open Window" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="379,264,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="myBtn_Click" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public void myBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        // ...
    }
}
```

And when you want to assign created earlier style to the button, you should use `StaticResource` and name of your style:

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource myBtnStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an exact clone, then you will need to serialize the component and inject an ExpressionConverter into the serialization process. This will create a 'deep' clone. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541/how-can-you-clone-a-wpf-object).