# Custom control - Listview with no predefined content WPF/c#

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I used for the first time a custom Control (wpf). Here is what I want:

[image]

I want a Custom ListView with Custom ListViewItem (the challenge is I don’t know what’s on the “Form”, I just know it’s a `Panel` - I call "Form" what's on the ListViewItem ).

I have a CustomListView and a CustomListViewItem  :

**EDIT : CustomListView.cs**

```cs
    public class CustomListView : ItemsControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ListContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ListContent", typeof(IList), typeof(CustomListView), new PropertyMetadata());
        public IList ListContent
        {
            get { return (IList)GetValue(ListContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ListContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public CustomListView(ContentControl contentControl, IList list)
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomListView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomListView)));
            DataContext = list;
            ItemsSource = list;

            CustomListViewItem customListViewItem = new CustomListViewItem();
            customListViewItem.Content = contentControl;

            string xamlTemplate = XamlWriter.Save(customListViewItem);
            string template =
               "<DataTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>" +
                    xamlTemplate +
               "</DataTemplate>";

            ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(template); 

            SetValue(TemplateContentProperty, contentControl);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT : CustomListViewItem .cs**

```cs
public class CustomListViewItem : ContentControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyEventProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyEvent", typeof(EventHandler), typeof(CustomListViewItem));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListContentItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ListContentItem", typeof(IList), typeof(CustomListViewItem), new PropertyMetadata());

    public IList ListContentItem
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(ListContentItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ListContentItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        get { return (EventHandler)GetValue(MyEventProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyEventProperty, value); }
    }

    public CustomListViewItem()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomListViewItem);
    }

    //Some method for the Event on my button
```

The `DataContext` of the CustomListView is an ObservableCollection. When I create the “Form” directly on my CustomListViewItem, everything is perfect. I can sort with my button, add a new empty Form…

Now here is my problem.

Let’s say we have a class Person (with only a name) who implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. We create some “Person” and add them to an `ObservableCollection`. On a new xaml element, we create a Template (PersonEditor) the “Form”, with some Binding.

What I want on the `MainWindows` is something like that:

```cs
CustomListView customListView = new CustomListView(new PersonEditor(), _person);
myContentControl.Content = customListView;
```

Where _person is the `ObservableCollection`. We give the Template of the Form to the CustomListViewItem and add it to a content of a ContentControl

**EDIT : Generics.xaml :**

```cs
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type customControl:CustomListView}" TargetType="customControl:CustomListView" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ItemsControl}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type customControl:CustomListView}">
                <Border>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type customControl:CustomListViewItem}"  TargetType="customControl:CustomListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}">
    <Setter Property="ListContentItem">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding Path="ListContent" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=customControl:CustomListView}"></Binding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="customControl:CustomListViewItem">
                <Border Background="White" x:Name="borderSelect" Padding="0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                    <DockPanel Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0">
                                <StackPanel SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                                    <Button SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Style="{StaticResource SquareCorner}" Opacity="0.0" Margin="0 7 0 0"  Height="30" Width="12" VerticalAlignment="top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="x" Padding="0" x:Name="DeleteButton" Command="{TemplateBinding MyEvent}"/>
                                    <StackPanel SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundUpCorner}" Opacity="0.0" Margin="0 7 0 0" Height="15" Width="15" VerticalAlignment="top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="^" Padding="0 0 0 5" x:Name="UpButton" Command="{TemplateBinding MyEvent}"/>
                                        <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundDownCorner}" Opacity="0.0" Height="15" Width="15" VerticalAlignment="top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="v" Padding="0" x:Name="DownButton" Command="{TemplateBinding MyEvent}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                 </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Button Style="{StaticResource SquareLittleCorner}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Opacity="0.0" Height="15" Width="15" VerticalAlignment="top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1 0 0 0" Content="+" Padding="0" x:Name="AddUpButton" Command="{TemplateBinding MyEvent}"/>
                                <Button Style="{StaticResource SquareLittleCorner}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Opacity="0.0" Height="15" Width="15" VerticalAlignment="bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1 0 0 0" Content="+" Padding="0" x:Name="AddButton" Command="{TemplateBinding MyEvent}"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The result is I only have one element that has the good Template, the other ones are created but empty.

I think the problem comes from the binding. But I don’t know what to do. I tried to create a new “Form” with xamlReader/xamlLoad ([How can you clone a WPF object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541/how-can-you-clone-a-wpf-object)) but with the binding again it’s not good. I also tried to clone the xaml but again, no binding and no event on button.

I don’t know what else I can do to solve this problem ? It’s my first time with a custom control so if I made a mistake (anything) just share please.

**EDIT**

I think my custom is better now, I follow the idea of the `DataTemplate` and `ContentControl` mix with xamlReader/xamlLoad. The Binding is good (same for Event). But, why when I used it before (like a Content not a Template) the Binding wasn't good ? And I don't know if xamlReader/xamlLoad is a good way to do that (I mean it looks more like some cheat).

Comment: You need to use `DataTemplate` with `ContentPresenter`, not `ContentControl`.  However, you probably shouldn't be doing this in the first place.  Just use `ItemsControl`.

Comment: At first I use ItemsControl on my CustomListView but I don't manage to have what I want with the event. So I create the CustomListViewItem. I try to add a ContentPresenter but I don't see what I have to do with the DataTemplate

Comment: You shouldn't need an event on the item at all.  THat should be part of your ViewModel.

Comment: Ok so maybe I don't use the custom control like I'm suppose to do. I want event on the item because I want them to have button on the outside (like an arrow to up the position of the item)

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what you need so we can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF. subclassing WPF UI elements is usually not the right approach. Neither is XAMLReader and the like.

Comment: I can't yet sorry I'm new on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Lenny upload the image to `imgur.com` or something, then link to that in your question. Any user with some rep can edit your question and embed the image in the question itself.

Comment: Oh Ok nice advice http://imgur.com/SUryb8X

Comment: In 99% of cases you are doing it wrong if you use events in WPF. The 1 % is when you are writing UI elements. WPF should only use events internally.

Comment: The custom is use like an "Advanced List View". The user can add it (or not) on its application.