# Change null value appearance on DataGrid when binding to DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datatable

I have `DataGrid`, which binds to `DataTable`, because i don't know the amount of columns at compile time.

**`XAML`**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfApplication1:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataTable}" />
</Grid>
```

**`MainWindowViewModel.cs`**

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DataTable dt;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Foo", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Bar", typeof(string));
        table.Rows.Add(1, "first");
        table.Rows.Add(2, null);
        DataTable = table;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string s)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(s));
        }
    }

    public DataTable DataTable
    {
        get { return dt; }
        set
        {
            dt = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DataTable");
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image: simple table]

There is nothing in the cell with `null` value. 
**My question is**: How can i change all the cells with `null` value to '-' without changing the source `DataTable`.

I can't use converter in binding because it will try to convert all the `DataTable`, not the values.
I had no luck with `DataGridCell` styles also because i don't know how to get the data value and change it.

**`Edit`**

My final solution is based on one of the answers. I create `MyDataGrid` class and override `OnAutoGeneratingColumn` method.

```
class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        var textColumn = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;

        if (textColumn != null)
        {
            var binding = textColumn.Binding;
            binding.TargetNullValue = "-";
        }

        base.OnAutoGeneratingColumn(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am just guessing here...can we inherit DataTable and use this new DataTable type for binding?

Comment: @theinsaneone i don't see how it can help

Comment: oh sry...the answer below is the best approach...i went too far for this solution :P my bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe to the AutoGeneratingColumn-Event and replace the Binding with one, which has FallbackValue/TargetNullValue set to your liking. For cloning i used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14740448/3411327).

```
    private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridTextColumn textColumn;
        if ((textColumn = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn) != null)
        {
            var binding = textColumn.Binding;
            var clone = binding.CloneBinding();
            clone.FallbackValue = "-----";
            clone.TargetNullValue = "-----";
            textColumn.Binding = clone;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That was a great idea, thanks. I create `MyDataTable:DataTable` and modified `OnAutoGeneratingColumn` method based on your approach.

Comment: Yet i have one question: why do you clone the binding object?

Comment: Ah, right. In this scenario this is not necessary. If the binding was obtained by BindingOperations.GetBinding() it would throw an exception when trying to change a value of the binding. Since the binding here is just set to a CLR-Property you don't need to clone it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the null value in datatable as shown below:

```
if (dt != null)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Tables[0].Columns)
        {
            string type = col.DataType.Name;

            if (row.IsNull(col))
            {
                if (type == "String") //for string values
                {
                    row.SetField(col, "-");
                }
                else // for integer
                {
                    row.SetField(col, 0);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is one way to do it, but i was trying to find a solution without changing the DataTable if it is possible.

Comment: You can do the same in grid cell value and replace

Comment: I would like to stay inside MVVM pattern, and not use some manual editing

Answer (score 2):

You can try use this function:

```
private string SomeString = null;

...

table.Rows.Add(2, ReturnNullValue(SomeString, "---"));

private string ReturnNullValue(string Value, string NullValue) 
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Value) == true)
    {
        return NullValue;
    }

    return Value;
}
```

Or you can add the property with additional logic:

```
private string _someString = "";

public string SomeString
{
    get
    {
        return _someString;
    }

    set
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == false)
        {
            _someString = value;
        }
        else
        {
            _someString = "---";
        }
    }
}
```

And use like this:

```
SomeString = "";
table.Rows.Add(2, SomeString);
```

I think we can do it without editing `DataTable`, that is no simple and quick solution, because Converter, Style and [`TargetNullValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) powerless here.

Comment: Thanks, this is one way to do it, but i was trying to find a solution without changing the DataTable if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a `ViewModel` class that inherits `DataTable` or just keeps a reference of that `DataTable` class. That `ViewModel` class is what you bind to the `DataGrid`'s ItemSource. The `ViewModel` should then know what data it should or shouldn't convert (`null`s to "-") and return to the `DataGrid`. That way the `DataTable` remains unchanged.